# Problem assigning JMS variable with database variable

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, soa, jdeveloper

So I am new with Oracle SOA Suite 12c and JDeveloper. I am still learning but the issue is I can't find enough information online about the errors I encounter while developing the services. For this service I have to consume queue data from JMS server and store them on the database. However I am coming across some errors

So I have created a service consisting of a JMS adapter connected with BPEL which is connected to DB adapter. Now when I add data on JMS queue, it is consumed by my service however when I have to assign the values, I get the following error for assign activity:

```
<bpelFault><faultType>0</faultType><selectionFailure xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"></selectionFailure></bpelFault>
```

Here is my BPEL:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<process name="BPELProcess1"
           targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Application22/listenqueue/BPELProcess1"
               xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
               xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Application22/listenqueue/BPELProcess1"
               xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
               xmlns:bpelx="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"
               xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/jms/Application22/listenqueue/jmsService"
         xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/Application22/listenqueue/db"
         xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.org" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/top/db">

  <!--
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ORCHESTRATION LOGIC
     Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the
     services integrated within this business process
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  -->
  <partnerLinks>
    <partnerLink name="jmsService" partnerLinkType="ns1:Consume_Message_plt" myRole="Consume_Message_role"/>
    <partnerLink name="db" partnerLinkType="ns2:db_plt" partnerRole="db_role"/>
  </partnerLinks>
  <variables>
    <variable name="Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable" messageType="ns1:Consume_Message_msg"/>
    <variable name="Invoke1_insert_InputVariable" messageType="ns2:UsersCollection_msg"/>
  </variables>
  <sequence name="main">
    <receive name="Receive1" partnerLink="jmsService" portType="ns1:Consume_Message_ptt" operation="Consume_Message"
             variable="Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable" createInstance="yes"/>
    <assign name="Assign1">
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:USERID</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:userid</to>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:FNAME</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:fname</to>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:USERSTATE</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:userstate</to>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:MOBILE</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:mobile</to>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:EMAIL</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:email</to>
      </copy>
      <copy>
        <from>$Receive1_Consume_Message_InputVariable.body/ns3:USERID/ns3:USERTYPE</from>
        <to expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">$Invoke1_insert_InputVariable.UsersCollection/ns4:Users/ns4:usertype</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>
    <invoke name="Invoke1" partnerLink="db" portType="ns2:db_ptt" operation="insert"
            inputVariable="Invoke1_insert_InputVariable" bpelx:invokeAsDetail="no"/>
  </sequence>
</process>
```

but the thing is, the receiver is able to receive the data but idk why when i try to assign the values I get the error that the values are null. What do I do?